# How to display the Facebook wall posts in android application.?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, floating-action-button

Am new to developing, am trying to get posts from facebook wall and displaying in my android application.
Am able to read all posts from facebook wall, using the below code(am printing the Json result).

```
GraphRequest g = new GraphRequest(accessToken, "/me/posts", null, HttpMethod.GET, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
            String output = "";
            int ids = 0;
            JSONObject jsonObject = graphResponse.getJSONObject();
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("data");
    System.out.println("cccccccccccccccaaaaaaaaaaaa" + jsonArray);


        }
    });
   g.executeAsync();
```

**am integrate the ID example1@facebook.com to my android application. i want to display posts from example1@facebook.com this  FB account to my android app, when i authenticate my android app with example1@facebook.com this account its displaying the posts if i logged in with another (example2@facebook.com)FB account means it not displaying the posts**

is this possible to get the posts from integrated app or not..

Please help.